# Moodle Integration with Microsoft Teams

Tags: office365, ms-office, moodle, microsoft-teams

i recently made the Office 365 integration with Moodle, specifically i want to use Microsoft Teams for video conference, Synchronization of courses is going great but from what i read in instructions it should also assign members and owners to each created group (course) based on Moodle participants - this is not happening though, any ideas?

Comment: How are you integrating? Is it a plugin?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us. We are investigating this issue internally, will get back to you soon

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Moodle by Skooler](https://skooler.com/moodle-by-skooler/) this will help you in understanding the sync with meeting and classroom.